# What PointCloud library would be the best to start working with for a beginner?

Tags: computer-vision, point-clouds, robotics

I am looking to learn to work with a pointcloud library. As a beginner, what would be the best library to use? I have heard about PCL, CGAL, PDAL etc. but am not sure which one to use. My main interests are at the intersection of classical computer vision, deep learning and robotics. I am using a Windows machine without a GPU (I know that using a Linux Machine with a GPU would be ideal, but at the moment, this is what I have). Also, I have moderate but not expert experience with C++.

Comment: I think PCL is much easier to use than CGAL, and much more complete with regards to point clouds. I have no experience with PDAL.

Comment: Each of them is great. Like every tool, it depends on what you need and with what. For difficult level, PDAL -> PCL -> CGAL. PDAL is probably the easiest but is fewer C++. PCL compare to the other 2 is limited (More you can do with PDAL or CGAL) but don't get me wrong is still a great tool. I would say CGAL is the most advanced but has also a higher starting point and is harder to use than the other two.